# Why am I getting: "can't find '__main__' module in '' " error when using interpreter?

Tags: python, flask, web-development-server

I'm following a flask tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_templates.htm

I copy and paste this code into the python interpreter/command shell:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello/<user>')
def hello_name(user):
   return render_template('hello.html', name = user)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

It gives me this message: can't find '**main**' module in ''

However, it works fine when I save it into a file and execute it.

Comment: note, the above duplicate was the first hit on google when I searched for "python flask can't find 'main' module in ''"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That post wasn't even on the first page of search results for me

Comment: Maybe it's because Google knows I spend too much time on StackOverflow